# Firefox bad rendering

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, firefox

I'm only facing this issue on **Firefox** (IE,Safari and Chrome render fine).

[Here](http://accountabletest.com/services) you can see how **the banner's height changes upon reload**. Moreover, if you move the pointer towards the links in the sidebars **a whole div also changes place**. `There's no javascript in the code. No % in margins or paddings.` I won't copy the whole CSS code because it's really big, but an accurate inspection from someone who had experienced these issues should be enough.

Comment: You need to copy the *relevant* portion of the code here. Can you reproduce it in a minimal test case using [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Sounds like a extraneous `display: block;`...

Comment: @p.s.w.g , I can't because this is a Wordpress theme I'm working on.

Comment: @Kroltan, there's not a `display: block;` used in the code.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have a doctype and, therefore, are in [quirks mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode) where you never want to be. It's like 1999 all over again. Add this to the first line of your page and let us know how it goes: `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Unfortunately, creating the site while in quirks means, once you put the doctype in and get switched to "standards mode", your layout may change around because everything is being rendered as it should have been in the first place.

A doctype is required of all modern web pages and should be the very first thing put down when creating one.

[Here is a great overall review.](https://hsivonen.fi/doctype/)

Comment: Hi @Rob, I completely understand what you mean. This is a Wordpress template. The header.php contains the `<!DOCTYPE html>`, but it was called after some divs. Now if you reload you'll see the `<!DOCTYPE html>` is the very first thing in the code. Still the issue is present.

Comment: @Gonpires The doctype must be the very first element on the very first line with nothing preceding it. It cannot be placed anywhere else.

Comment: I understand and now it is the very first thing. However, the problem remains.

Comment: @Gonpires It is not. There is something on line 1. Spaces count, too. Also, did anything change in the other browsers? Make sure you refresh the page. Note that this issue is with IE, not other browsers.

Comment: @Gonpires By "this issue" I mean IE will still go into quirks with anything preceding the doctype. btw, Chrome now shows you are in standards mode.

Comment: It's on the very first line, no spaces before. Could my problem be caused by something else? I really need the webpage to be compatible with Firefox..

Comment: I don't see any differences between Firefox and Chrome now.

Comment: Please clear your Firefox cache, you'll see how the content pointed in the description (banner's height. headwhite 2 Div while pointing over the sidebar's links) is still moving in Firefox, but not in Chrome.

Comment: Yes, I see this now. There is a ton of javascript running whether you see it or not. I'm looking through it while I can.

Comment: thank you, you would really really make my week If you help me out with this Firefox issue.

Comment: there are some plugins used that use custom javascript, but I've used the same ones with the same wordpress theme on another web page and this is not happening. Might it be associated with some hover effect?